# C working with big files, fseek and fread

Tags: c, file, io, fread

I am writing a program where it can happen that i need to access files bigger than ~2GB. Would just using fseek and fread without ftell work for bigger files?

```
int main() {
  unsigned long long int len;
  unsigned char *buffer; /* i know its not initialized */
  unsigned char *sbuffer = buffer;

  FILE *fp = fopen("test123", "rb");
  fread(fp, 8, 1, (void*) &len);

  while (len >= LONG_MAX) {
    fread(fp, 1, LONG_MAX, (void*) sbuffer);
    sbuffer += LONG_MAX;
    len -= LONG_MAX;
  }
  if (len) {
    fread(fp, 1, len, (void*) sbuffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: You set `len` by reading the first 8 bytes of the file. But, you _never_ decrement it in your `while` loop, so you'll loop forever. Add `len -= LONG_MAX;` to the bottom of the loop. But, you should really do: `while (len >= LONG_MAX) { unsigned long long cur = fread(fp, 1, LONG_MAX, (void *) sbuffer); if (cur != LONG_MAX) break; len -= cur; sbuffer += LONG_MAX; }` But, `LONG_MAX` is not a good choice in any case. Use a shorter buffer (e.g. 64KB) since you're looping in chunks.

Comment: Your snippet has no fseek in it. The argument for fread is size_t, not long, its max value is SIZE_MAX, if that is smaller than LONG_MAX, you're in trouble. buffer is not initialized (it's nice that you know it, but it's still wrong). No error handling. And the answer may also depend on the capabilities of your file system.

Comment: It's about the idea and I didn't know how to represent fseek. But could I just continuosly jump forward with SEEK_CUR, and fread also moves the pointer

Comment: The basic idea of sequential reads and relative seeks will work with large files on (probably) all the mainstream OSs. However, I don't see anything in the relevant standards that would guarantee it. Are you interested in some specific environment or do you want a maximally portable solution?

Comment: Mainly Windows, Linux and other Unixes, so nothing to obscure. And I'd like to go for max portability.

Comment: Use `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` instead?

Comment: You can't jump forward with fsetpos

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the 64 bit variants of `fread64`, `fseek64`, etc. or you can use `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` before you include the headers.

Comment: This isn't platform independent